# Why ${x}_{1}={a}_{1} {e}^{i \omega t}$ and ${x}_{2}={a}_{2} {e}^{i \omega t}$ ansatzs work in solutions to coupled oscillator DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

in two coupled harmonic oscillator differential equations, we use ansatzs of the form ${x}_{1}={a}_{1} {e}^{i \omega t}$ and ${x}_{2}={a}_{2} {e}^{i \omega t}$ . And it works by giving us the frequencies as the roots of zeroes of polynomials. This trick works. Can I know exactly why this trick works?
Coupled DE:
$m \ddot{x}_{1}+k x_{1}+k^{\prime}\left(x_{1}-x_{2}\right)=0$
$m \ddot{x}_{2}+k x_{2}-k^{\prime}\left(x_{1}-x_{2}\right)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand why it works for a differential equation of the form $$y''+ay'+by=0,$$ then you should be able to see why it works for systems of such equations (of course, $a$ and $b$ have to be constants). So why does it work for the above equation? First rewrite it in the form $$y''+ay'=-by,$$ and you're asking yourself what function of $x$ which when differentiated once, twice gives you back a constant multiple of itself? Well, from elementary calculus we know that this is the property of the exponential functions, which leads us to trying $y=e^{mx}$ for some constant $m$ to be determined.

Comment: Yes, I just missed this point :)